# How do I align two divs horizontally without the left one floating left?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have 2 div elements I want centered in my page. The outter div is 100% width and text-align: center. Like so:

```
    div.centerpanel {
    font-size: 28px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The two elements contained within it should appear next to each other but centered (they're both simply divs with text content). Simply put, I want a centered title on my page, each of the two words of the title being a seperate div. I read that you do the following to accomplish this:

```
float: left;
clear: none;
```

As far as I can tell, the 'clear' does not have any visible effect. When I add the float: left, to the first of the two elements, it simply causes that element to slide all the way to the extreme left of the outer .centerpanel while the element that follows it remains out in the middle where it should be. So it's definitely aligning it properly but inexplicably sends it all the way to the left.

How do I make it stay vertically aligned with it's following element but keep obeying the outer div's text-align: center?

Comment: Add `clear: both;` to the parent div. Floating the element breaks it out of the flow of the page

Comment: `display: inine-block;` on the `div`'s you want to center. Remove the float and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `display:inline-block;` on your child elements. View this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rq17uwvw/) for an example of how to accomplish this.

HTML:

```
<div class="centerpanel">
<div class="leftpanel">Left</div><div class="rightpanel">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.centerpanel {
font-size: 28px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align: center;
}
.leftpanel {
background:red;
display:inline-block;
width:50%;
}
.rightpanel {
background:blue;
display:inline-block;
width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this is what you want to have. And of course there are more than one ways to skin a cat.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="centerpanel">
        <div class="left">L</div>
        <div class="right">R</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.centerpanel {
    font-size: 28px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.centerpanel div{
    width: 50%;    
}

.left{
    float: left;
}

.right{
    float: right;
}

.clearfix{
    clear: both;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfpdpmze/2/

Since there are only two `div`s here, you could also set them `display: inline-block` without using any flotation.

**Side note:**

There are of course more modern ways of clearing floating. One of them is by setting up the `overflow` property on the container of the `div`s that get floated. More about that here: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: I would have add the clearfix class to the right div and use clearfix::after instead of use an empty div.

Comment: You beat me to the inline-block response but I posted an example of how it could be accomplished without the use of floats below.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- there's great info here. The only difference here is that the elements were not next to each other, they were spaced apart. It turns out the use of display: inline-block fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<div style="display:flex">
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <span>Content1</span>
                </div>
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <span>Content2</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```